# Core Data: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator - cannot perform a save operation

Tags: ios, core-data

About 5 seconds after launching my app and making a few fetch requests, it crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

I'm using Core Data with just two entities and a couple of properties, no UITableViewControllers, fetch delegates and stuff. Obviously I can't copy/paste all my app's code here, but I'm sure I made a silly mistake somewhere.

Any directions where to look?

Comment: Looks like it's fixed. I deleted the datamodel file, wiped the simulator and it seems to be working so far. Would be nice to know what went wrong though.

Comment: Previous entity had stored and you change data model, clear simulator content anytime you change data model.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily the best approach to just delete everything. Remember, once your app is deployed you do not have that option. While this might be a viable way in development, you should be aware of the correct procedure:

When you change the managed object model, make a new version first. If your persistent store has these options set:

- `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and
- `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`

there is no need to delete the store in order to make it work.